# Spring Boot REST API Endpoint Mapping best practice

Tags: rest, api, web-services, spring-boot, microservices

I am using below endPoint  URL Mapping with HTTP Methods like ( POST, DELETE, GET, PUT)

POST for Create a new Trade -

`@PostMapping("/trade")`

DELETE for Delete a Trade with specific id -

`@DeleteMapping("/trade/{id}")`

GET for Get details of specific Trade -

`@GetMapping("/trade/{id}")`

PUT for Update Trade details -

`@PutMapping(“/trade/{id}”)`

GET for Retrieve all Trade list of the collection -

`@GetMapping("/trades")`

Spring currently supports five types of inbuilt annotations for handling different types of incoming HTTP request methods which are GET, POST, PUT, DELETE and PATCH. These annotations are:

```
@GetMapping
@PostMapping
@PutMapping
@DeleteMapping
@PatchMapping
```

From the naming convention, we can see that each annotation is meant to handle the respective incoming request method types, i.e. @GetMapping is used to handle GET type of request method, @PostMapping is used to handle POST type of request method, etc.

if I am missing anything here Please suggest

Comment: you need to specify API version

Answer (score 2):

Add API version like

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/API/V1")
public class TestController {

@RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting( {
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer seems to be missing a RequestMethod?

Answer (score 0):

For versioning there are several approaches you can use:

1. **URI path**:
   Include the version number in the URL path of the endpoint.
   For example `v1` in `/api/v1/trade`:

```
public class TradeController {

  @GetMapping("v1/trade")
  public Trade tradeVersionOne() {
    return new Trade("123","Trade Result");
  }

  @GetMapping("v2/trade")
  public Trade tradeVersionTwo() {
    return new Trade(new RealTimeTrade("123", "Real Time Trade Result"));
  }

}
```

2. **Query parameters**:
   Pass the version number as a query parameter with a specified name.
   For example: `?version=1` in `/api/trade?version=1`:

```
public class TradeController {

  @GetMapping(name = "v1/trade", params = "version=1")
  public Trade tradeVersionOne() {
    return new Trade("123","Trade Result");
  }

  @GetMapping(name = "v2/trade", params = "version=2")
  public Trade tradeVersionTwo() {
    return new Trade(new RealTimeTrade("123", "Real Time Trade Result"));
  }
 }
```

3. **Custom HTTP headers**:
   Define a new header that contains the version number in the request.
4. **Content negotiation**:
   Include the version number in the `Accept` header along with the accepted content type.