# Spring Boot request mappings best practices

Tags: spring-boot

I've been looking into Spring Boot and in the tutorials I've done the request mappings are give like this:

```
@GetMapping("/hello")
```

If the mapping is referenced elsewhere it's done by repeating the same string:

```
.antMatchers("/hello").permitAll()
```

It feels to me like this could get messy with larger applications so I'm wondering if there's something "everyone" is doing to organize this and avoid repetition of strings with the problems that come from doing that with typos, etc.

Comment: what if define urls in a properties file ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot REST API Endpoint Mapping best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51035930/spring-boot-rest-api-endpoint-mapping-best-practice)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51035930/spring-boot-rest-api-endpoint-mapping-best-practice

Comment: In my experience, when you combine constants to build URL´s, they end up being very difficult to read. A good practice is to create MockMvc-tests for all endpoints, they will fail if you change a URL by mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no silverbullet that I am aware of. Make sure you structure your application properly. I find that having all my controllers in the same package helps. I also try to keep each controller relatively small.

Taking care when designing and naming controllers may relieve some potential future pain. 
For example:

- `CustomerController`
- `InvoiceController`
- `OrderController`
- `ProductController`

You should also enable Spring boot to log all endpoints on startup. Se [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53739836/1752614)

Another option is to try https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-hateoas/

Comment: It seems logging and testing endpoints is the way to go no matter how I choose to organise them. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can organize your URLs in constant like this

```java
    public class UrlConstant {

        public static final String ID_PLACEHOLDER = "/{id}";

        public static class HelloUrl {

            public static final String URL = "/hello";

            public static class Path {

                public static final String TEST = "/test";

            }

            public static class QueryParam {

                public static final String PARAM1 = "param";

            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can add

`public static final HELLO_URI = "/hello"`

and import this variable where you need it

this protect you from problems after project changes

You can add it to some class which contains constants or to your RestController class

Answer (score 1):

On the applications I’ve been working on, it is usually a mix.

First, you don’t need to specify every endpoint. Most of the times, it will be protected given a root URL, like `/api/**`. 
Second, use constants in your Controller, and annotate it with the prefix URL you will use `@RequestMapping(UserController.PREFIX)` and use the same constants in your `WebSecurity` and `mvcMatchers(UserController.PREFIX)`.

By the way, it is better to use `mvcMatchers` instead of `antMatchers`. Check spring security doc for more information.